# how to add a page

Tags: customization, pages

It's probably really simple, but i can't figured out, i have a php file and 3 folders css, js( with inside libs ), and image.
so i put the php file and the css inside the theme root, the js in /js folder.
after that i just created a new page and use as template attributes the about. doesn't work

http://www.inspirates.net/?page_id=554

there is the file: http://pastebin.com/YYP31cfr

i don't know what is wrong, i know there are a lot of topic about custom page, but my problem is to include all the file.

Comment: Are you talking about page templates?

Answer (score 0):

The code you have pasted has errors - the get_header() is fine but then you have HTML code in PHP code areas.

Also you have included the header twice. Check this code out http://pastebin.com/mH2tn3Qw

The header code should be placed in header.php if you are using the get_header() call